# Why is \str_if_eq_p:nn not evaluating to true?

Tags: expl3

In the following MWE, `\str_if_eq_p:nn` is not evaluating to true when `\l_aepoly_presentation_style_tl` is set to `ABC`.  Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_aepoly_presentation_style_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\mqpoly}{ D(){ABC} m }
  {\aepoly_parse_polynomial:nn {#1} {#2} }
\cs_new:Npn \aepoly_parse_polynomial:nn #1#2 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_aepoly_presentation_style_tl {#1}
  \bool_if:nTF {
      %% other possible boolean expressions to evaluate
      \str_if_eq_p:nn { \tl_to_str:N \l_aepoly_presentation_style_tl } { ABC }
    }
      { \iow_term:n { string ~ is ~ "ABC" } }
      { \iow_term:x { NOT ~ EQUAL -> ~ "\l_aepoly_presentation_style_tl" } }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\mqpoly(MNP){hello}

\mqpoly{hello}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah ha!  I need to be using `\str_if_eq_x_p:nn` to get the expansion of the token list.

Comment: I guess then either a self-answer or delete

Comment: Or `\str_if_eq_p:Vn \l_aepoly_..._tl {ABC}` (after defining the variant).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two workarounds:

1. use `\str_if_eq_x_p:nn` in order to force full expansion
2. use `\str_if_eq_p:Vn` in order to access the value of the token list variable

Which one is just a matter of preferences, but I'd go with the second, because it avoids expansion in the second argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mqpoly}{ D(){ABC} m }
  {\aepoly_parse_polynomial:nn {#1} {#2} }

\tl_new:N \l_aepoly_presentation_style_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \aepoly_parse_polynomial:nn #1#2
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_aepoly_presentation_style_tl {#1}
  \bool_if:nTF
   {
    %% other possible boolean expressions to evaluate
    \str_if_eq_p:Vn \l_aepoly_presentation_style_tl { ABC }
   }
   { \iow_term:n { string ~ is ~ "ABC" } }
   { \iow_term:x { NOT ~ EQUAL ~ -> ~ "\l_aepoly_presentation_style_tl" } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\mqpoly(MNP){hello}

\mqpoly{hello}

\end{document}
```

Don't forget to use `\cs_new_protected:Npn`, as you're doing an assignment in the function.

The output is

```
NOT EQUAL -> "MNP"
string is "ABC"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you're recommendation to use `\cs_new_protected:Npn`.  Are assignments not expandable?

Comment: @A.Ellett Right so: assignments are the main cause for misfunction of `\edef`. This macro is, of course, a stripped down version of something more complex; in the present function, the assignment is redundant, as you can directly pass `#1` to `\str_if_eq_p:nn`.

Comment: @A.Ellett I can't see it.